# Fixing bugged filter CSS property transition (Chrome)?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, transition

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/97w8440o/)

I'm trying to animate the `filter: blur()` property of an element on hover. e.g:

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-300-300-9.jpg);
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transition: all .45s linear;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
  filter: blur(10px);
}
```

It works, but seems to be bugged in Chrome. The animation executes but until it finishes, the edges of the image are blurred. It's fine in Firefox and Safari. Any ideas how I can circumvent this issue? The intended result is that it animates without any blurred edges visible at any point.

Answer (score 2):

EDITED:

Add to the .child:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-perspective: 1000;
```

```css
.parent {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .child {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-300-300-9.jpg);
        transform: scale(1.2);
        transition: all .45s linear;
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    }

    .parent:hover .child {
        -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
        filter: blur(10px);
    }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't eliminate the blurred edges.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I tried to change the transform property on the child and it works, just replace it with:

```
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1.2);
```

This trick resolves a lot of weird animations on webkit browsers.

https://davidwalsh.name/translate3d

Comment: Blurred edges are still present - not the expected result

Answer (score 0):

You could do with a workaround by adding box-shadow to the parent on hover to counter the bright edges. [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jarun87/0kqo7v19/)

Html

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.45s linear;
}

.child {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-300-300-9.jpg);
    transform: scale(1.2) translate3d(0,0,0);
    transition: all 0.45s linear;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.parent:hover .child {
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    filter: blur(10px);
}

.parent:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -50px -50px 50px -40px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

filter: blur(.3px)

.3px almost not affecting the screen and still animatable instead of 0px